# `su` command: Permission denied

Tags: bash, fedora, permissions, su

When I type into bash the following command `su -s /bin/bash` as root, then no error occurs.

When I type `su -s /bin/bash -m [MyUserName]`, then I get the error: `Permission denied.`

As far as I could find out, it has something to do with the `/etc/bashrc` file.

I looked: `/etc` has permissions `754` and `/etc/bashrc` has permissions `544`

There are a lot of adives to change the permission to allow execution of that file. Question: Do I really need execution permission? Why? Or is there any other way to solve that problem?

**EDIT**

There are some demands to give some more information. So here are they:

The command `su -s /bin/bash -m [MyUserName]` is the command I extracted from the whole command `su -s /bin/bash -m [MyUserName] /some/path/tomcat/bin/startup.sh -[some] [args]`.

First I thought, it has something to do with tomcat, but when I can type in `su -s /bin/bash -m [MyUserName]` without the tomcat part then the problem is not the tomcat part. As far as I know, the whole command is used, to start command as a special user.

Comment: If I'm right, this command would execute bash in your own name, preserving the environment (your user name isn't an argument of -m option because it doesn't take any). Why would you do that ? From which user are you executing this command ?

Comment: I think OP rather want root -> myuser. there is no need to change /etc/bashrc, this file is read by /bin/bash. can you give us the result of `which su` ?

Comment: @Archemar: `/usr/bin/su`

Comment: `su - myuser` should work. Can you log into myuser ? does it (myuser) have a proper shell ? does it home  dir (the one specifyied in /etc/passwd) is writable ?

Comment: No, you don't need execute permissions on `/etc/bash.bashrc`. Could you [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to do? Why  would you want to run `su -s /bin/bash -m [MyUserName]`? The `-m` option enables monitor mode, it doesn't take a username as an argument.

Comment: If users don't have the 'x' permission for `/etc`, programs that want to read files in it are going to complain and possibly fail to run. If you want to protect certain files in `/etc`, it's probably better to address them individually. What are your requirements?

Answer (score 4):

The problem is your permissions for `/etc`. These must be `755`, not `754`.

The full error text is as follows:

```
su -s /bin/bash -m roaima
Password: _
bash: /etc/bash.bashrc: Permission denied
I have no name!
```

This shows that the system is struggling to read `/etc/passwd` to derive the details of your home directory, full name, etc.

Fix the permissions on `/etc` and the problem will resolve itself.

Answer (score 1):

Use the man page:

```
-m, -p, --preserve-environment
    Preserves  the  whole  environment, ie does not set HOME, SHELL,
    USER nor LOGNAME.
```

So running 'su -m ' as root will make bash to read ~/.bashrc which expands (due to preserved environment) to /root/.bashrc which you have no rights as user. Your /etc and /etc/bashrc permission are wrong also, it should be 755 for /etc & 644 for /etc/bashrc.

Comment: This does not work. I changed the permissions. Also for /root/.bashrc to `755`, but that does not help.

Comment: @kristian You've misunderstood my reply. I'm pointing out the reason why using the command (su -m as root) it's going to print (and only print) a "Permission denied". Changing arbitrary permission on files it's not a correct way to deal with this (hint /root must be at least 711 but you don't want that). Having read your edit, you might try the command 'su [user] -c "/some/path/tomcat/bin/startup.sh -[some] [args]"' and see if that works?